# PHP adds quotes when echo variable from mySQL field.

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a problem, have stored some encoded html into a mySQL database.
   but when I decode and echo the variable. it adds double quotes on to the output.

Code:

```
    $content = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
    $data    = $content['contentHTML'];
    $html    = html_entity_decode($data,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $output     = <<<MY_MARKER
$html
MY_MARKER;
echo $output;
```

---

```
$html = "I am going to hax0r your site, hahaha! <script type='text/javascript'> window.location = 'http://www.example.com/' </script>"
```

but it will add " when echoing to browser.

this works:

```
$str = <<<MY_MARKER
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World2!<br>");
</script>
MY_MARKER;

echo $str;
```

and this works:

```
$userInput = "I am going to hax0r your site, hahaha! <script type='text/javascript'> window.location = 'http://www.example.com/' </script>";
$str = <<<MY_MARKER
$userInput
MY_MARKER;
```

but my code outputs with quotes, so the javascript is printed out in the browser.

it's something to do with getting the text from mySQL...

thanks in advance

[screen grab of browser output, and web inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3xHA.png)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what is in the `contentHTML` column

Comment: You are printing out a srting

Comment: I am going to hax0r your site, hahaha! &amp;lt;script type=&amp;#039;text/javascript&amp;#039;&amp;gt; window.location = &amp;#039;http://www.example.com/&amp;#039; &amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;     from the database

Comment: $data   = $content['contentHTML'];
    
    //echo mb_detect_encoding($data);
    
$html   = html_entity_decode($data,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

Comment: $data encoding is ASCII

Comment: SOLUTION: use mysqli_real_escape_string to encode html and then store in mySql database.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: use mysqli_real_escape_string to encode html and then store in mySql database